# Can you only take positive numbers into a square root?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am thinking about when you are simplifying something like this $x(1/x)^{0.5}=x^{0.5}$ but if $x$ was negative then you have lost the sign why is this still valid or is it not?? Another example is $$\begin{align}-(4)^{0.5}&=-2,\\(4\times(-1)^2)^{0.5}&=-2,\\4^{0.5}&=-2,\\2&=-2\end{align}$$ which is not valid why is the difference??

Comment: @Amateur That looks like a fine answer to me! Why not post it as an answer?

Comment: I think you may have miss read the 4^0.5 bit its meant to say -4^0.5 which does = -2

Comment: Joseph: $(-4)^{1/2} = \sqrt{-4}$ which is not a real number. $-(4^{1/2}) \neq \sqrt{-4}$. Rather, $-(4^{1/2}) = -\sqrt 4 = -(2) = -2$.

Comment: no sorry again the - is not in the square root it is outside?

Comment: If $x$ is negative, say $-4$, then $x^{1/2} = (x)^{1/2} = (-4)^{1/2} = \sqrt{-4} \neq -2$.

Comment: @amWhy I don't know, somehow I prefer to comment, in case I am mistaken.

Comment: sorry it says -(4)^0.5=-(2) i.e -1 timesed by the sqrt of 4

Comment: You had better clean up your question. $-(4)^{1/2}$ is indeed defined. But then your function had better be $-(x)^{1/2}$, evaluated at $x = 4$. $x^{1/2}$, evaluated at $x = -4$ is not defined in the real numbers.

Comment: but why can't i take this minus one into the square root by squaring it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If -x^2=-(y^2)^0.5 then x^2=y^2 and x=y, but -x^2=((-1)^2.y^2)^.5 is not valid because ((-1)^2)^0.5 does not equal -1 but equals 1, if we are simply taking the positive square roots. From this we can conclude that we can only take positive nubmers into the squre root i.e. a(x)^0.5 = (xa^2)^0.5 if and only if a>=0.

Answer (score 3):

$4^{1/2}$ is defined to be the positive square root of $4$, so $4^{1/2} = 2$, not $−2$. However if you wanted to get all solutions of $x^2=4$, then $x = −2$ would be a solution. As for your simplification $\frac{x}{x^{1/2}}= x^{1/2}$, if $x$ is negative, then $x^{1/2}$ is not a real number so if you work with the real numbers this expression is undefined.

Comment: Well done! (+1). When I started at MSE, I lingered around, watching (2-3 months not evening confident enough to comment!), then commenting (1-2 months), then finally answering. I was "answer-shy" as you can see, watching everything until I finally had the courage to comment, then post answers.

Comment: @amWhy Thank you for the encouragement :). It would have been a great miss if you did not start posting answers, as you are amongst the most helpful users on MSE !

Comment: You're welcome! And thank you :-)